# How do test my inapppurchase in iTunes connect

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i am working in inapp-purchase in iOS sdk and i am complete all steps like create app in iTunes and **non-consumable app** in manage-inapppurchase on iTunes connect.my app status is **Waiting for upload** like below screen shot:

[image]

and my inappurchase status is **ready to submit**

[image]

code wise inapp-purchase functionality completed,but,i am tested my app is **SKProductsRequest** returns no product found...!

my main app bundle id like **com.mycompany.myapp** ,

and my in-app bundle id like **com.mycompany.paidapp**.

how do they test the inapp purchase steps to can any one guide me,please..!

my sample code is here:

```
- (void)loadStore {

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {
        NSLog(@"Parental-controls are disabled");

        request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.mycompany.paidapp"]];
        //request.delegate = self;
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request start];


    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Parental-controls are enabled");
    }

}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if (count > 0) 
    {
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Products found!");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductsLoadedNotification object:@"Product Found..!"];

    } else if (!validProduct) 
    {
        NSLog(@"No products available");
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductsLoadedNotification object:@"Product Not Found..!"];

    }

}
```

command prompt returns nslog always below output:

**`No products available`**

Comment: com.mycompany.paidapp product exist in your In-App-Purchase store?

Comment: @Mitesh Khatri not exist on app store...!

Comment: Then add it in your iTunes In-App-Purchase and try again.

Comment: @ Mitesh Khatri if i test in-app-purchase must upload binary to appstore?

Comment: No. You do not need to upload binary on app store.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12544/discussion-between-mitesh-khatri-and-hero-vs-zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for testing the in-App you can create an AppID along with some In-App contents, before releasing the app u should check it well.

For that reason the policy what I follow is as followed:
1. First upload an app.
2. Add in app contents.
3. Reject the binary by yourself.
Once you are ok with your In-App testing then reload the new binary to iTunes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Application Bundle name and iTunes application bundle name should be same. and product must be exist on iTunes.
Try below code:

```
[productIdentifierList addObject:@"CB001"];
[productIdentifierList addObject:@"CB002"];
[productIdentifierList addObject:@"CB003"];

        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifierList]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
```

CB001, CB002 is your product id on your iTunes.

It Works fine for me.

Comment: my in-app bundle id com.mycompany.inapp to replace to assign like [productIdentifierList addObject:@"com.mycompany.inapp"];?